# Can anyone recommend a good way to display stats on a web page?

Tags: php, html, statistics

I want to display statistics on my site - we have the figures, but would like to display them in some way that looks prettier than just displaying the numbers.

Has anyone done this before, and do you have any recommendations for software we could use?  Obviously open source would be ideal, although we might be willing to pay a small sum - they're not complicated stats though, so something simple would be best.

The mockup done by our designer is based on Google Analytics, but I think that may be a bit more than we need.

Essentially, there are 4 numbers, which change over time, so we would like to plot graphs showing each of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Keep It Simple, Silly. `<div style="background-color:#000000;width:<?=$percent?>%;">&nbsp;</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mockup is based on Google Analytics, than I would reccomend the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html). Another advantage could be that integrating this API is really easy (you have to load an url where Google makes the plot for you, so no need to install any library on server/homepage).

You could make [static, image based plots](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/index.html), and [interactive ones](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html#Example) also.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start using http://code.google.com/p/flot/ or possibly with http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: I'd definitly recommend highcharts. Easy to use and extremly powerful:)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using jpgraph http://jpgraph.net/  or graphpite http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/